# My Webservices not working PHP/MYSQL/JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, web-services, api

I have created web services but it is not working using cURL.
When I am using file_get_contents($request) it is working.

**I want to call it using cURL**

Server Input Code

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
$posts = array();
/* require the user as the parameter */
if(isset($_GET['roll']) and isset($_GET['name']))
{
    /* soak in the passed variable or set our own */
    $roll = $_GET['roll']; //no default
    $name = $_GET['name']; //no default
    /* grab the posts from the db */
    if($roll!="" and $name!="")
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('$roll','$name')";
        if(mysql_query($query,$dblink))
        {
            $posts[] = array('status'=>'Data Inserted');
        }
        else
        {
            $posts[] = array('status'=>'Not Inserted');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $posts[] = array('status'=>'Null Value sent');
    }
    /* disconnect from the db */
    @mysql_close($db);
}
else
{
    $posts[] = array('status'=>'Please check the arguments');
}
/* output in necessary format */
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts));
?>
```

Server Output Code is

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
/* require the user as the parameter */
$posts = array();
if(isset($_REQUEST['roll']))
{
    $posts = array();
    /* soak in the passed variable or set our own */

    $roll = $_REQUEST['roll']; //no default

    /* grab the posts from the db */
    if($roll!="")
    {
        if($roll=="All")
        {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT";
        }
        else 
        {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM  `STUDENT` WHERE roll =  '$roll'";
        }
        $result = mysql_query($query,$dblink) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);
        if(!$result)
        {
            $posts[] = array('status'=>'Roll Not Found');
        }
        else
        {
            /* create one master array of the records */    
            if(mysql_num_rows($result)) 
            {
            while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
                $posts[] = array('student'=>$post);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $posts[] = array('status'=>'Roll not Found');
        }
    }
}
else
{
    $posts[] = array('status'=>'Roll Should Not be Null');
}

/* disconnect from the db */
@mysql_close($db);
}
   else
   {
        $posts[] = array('status'=>'Please send Valid Argument');
   }
       /* output in necessary format */
        header('Content-type: application/json');
       echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts));
?>
```

**Call Using file_get_contents($request)  Its working**

```
<?php
     $request="https://returns.jabong.com/tracking/WebServices/server_output.php?roll=12MCA02";
     //$request="https://returns.jabong.com/tracking/WebServices/server_input.php?roll=12MCA02&name=Aneesh Khan";
    $response = file_get_contents($request);
    print_r($response);
?>
```

**Call using cURL - Its not working**

```
    $sUrl = "https://returns.jabong.com/tracking/WebServices/server_input.php";
    $sData = 'roll=12MCA05&name=Aneesh A Khan';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    $vRes = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    header('Content-Type: text/json');
    echo $vRes;
?>
```

Call is not working using cURL , Please help me soon ?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) And since your "service" script expects a GET request, why are you doing a POST in curl?

Comment: Because you are using https as the scheme I believe you need to add some more options to your curl request - such as CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, CURLOPT_CAINFO, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 1):

Your code was quite mixed up - you are requiring $_GET parameters in some places, $_REQUEST parameters in others and the curl function looks like it's attempting to send via POST - but there are options missing to force curl to send via POST. Using a simple GET request via curl with the parameters appended to the url the data gets inserted.

```
<?php

    $sUrl = "https://returns.jabong.com/tracking/WebServices/server_input.php";
    $sData = 'roll='.uniqid().'&name='.uniqid('user_',true);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sUrl . '?' . $sData );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );  

    $vRes = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $vRes;

?>
```

Which method is it you want to use? And, as @Marc pointed out this code is open to sql injection.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

Its working now.

In my original project I will take care of SQL INJUNCTION.